# Using jQuery to circumvent tabindex problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, tabindex

I'm trying to control my forms and how the user interacts with them via the form elements' `tabindex` property. All of my elements have `tabindex` specified, and I want this value to be respected and used properly.

I'm currently developing on Mac/Firefox and I'm aware of the default Mac system setting that sets tab-switching to only input elements and lists. However, I want to override this and any other settings that may get in the way of this on any system/browser.

I'm using jQuery to try to get around this. Here's my code at this point:

```
$(":input").keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which == 0)
    {
        tindex = parseInt($(this).attr("tabindex")) + 1;
        $(":input[tabindex='" + tindex + "']").focus();
    }
});
```

However, this isn't working in the way I want it to. When the default Mac setting is enabled, this actually skips a tabindex, and skips non-text/textarea items altogether. For example, if I'm on `input[tabindex=2]` and I press the "Tab" key, I'm sent to `input[tabindex=4]`. If I'm on `input[tabindex=2]` and there's a `select` box between `input[tabindex=2]` and `input[tabindex=4]`, I'm sent to `input[tabindex=5]`.

I want `input[tabindex=2]` to send me to `input[tabindex=3]`, `select[tabindex=3]`, `input[type=radio][tabindex=3]`, etc.; basically whatever has `tabindex` of 3.

Let me know of any ideas to circumvent this problem. Also please tell me if you know of anything else on any other systems/browsers that I should be looking at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `e.preventDefault();` to your keypress event handler. This will stop the browser from performing its default action on this event. This will also stop the browser from following a link if it's placed in a click handler.

See [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29).